# Does HashMap.clear() resize inner hash table to the original size?

Tags: java, hashmap

What happens to the HashMap after this code execution?

```
HashMap m  = new HashMap();
for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024; i++)
    m.put(i, i);
m.clear();
```

After 1M puts the inner hash table will grow from original 16 to 1MB. Does clear() resize it to the original size or not?

Comment: I guess, No. that will be extra work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The table retains its size. All elements are set to `null`:

```
public void clear() {
    modCount++;
    Entry[] tab = table;
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
        tab[i] = null;
    size = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an implementation detail, and I don't know [what API you're reading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) that says anything about 1M puts or an inner hash table.

Let's just look at an implementation:

```
  620       /**
  621        * Removes all of the mappings from this map.
  622        * The map will be empty after this call returns.
  623        */
  624       public void clear() {
  625           modCount++;
  626           Entry[] tab = table;
  627           for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
  628               tab[i] = null;
  629           size = 0;
  630       }
```

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html#621

So the OpenJDK 7 implementation does not restore the original size.